# Where can I find a citable reference for the formula for inverse distributions?

Tags: distributions, references, density-function

To be more specific: Let the random variable X be distributed according to probability density function f(x). Then the pdf of Y=1/X is given by g(y)=1/y^2 f(1/y), [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution).

I wonder if there is any citable reference for that. Or is it common knowledge?
I'm coming from a different field of mathematics and lack some background in statistics. I looked through some text books, but didn't find any mention of it yet.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The duplicate does not provide references because this is an extremely well-known relationship that can be found in any textbook that covers distribution functions (at least any that assumes some basic Calculus knowledge of its readers).

Comment: It's just standard [change of variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables). Easiest way to see it is by beginning with $P(Y\leq y)=P(1/X \leq y) =...$ (taking great care with the case where $X$ can be zero). The case where $X>0$ is simple, perhaps try it first. Once you have the cdf, take the derivative to get the density. As whuber says, it's in pretty much any standard text that covers this stuff.